# Prompting a file download on my web page

Tags: php, html, download

I wanted to serve a download of my program on special download page. Something like: `http://site.com/download`, where there will be a standard HTML page and also a file download prompt. I was wondering how I'd go about implementing this.

The only way I can think of is having a hidden iframe in the page pointing to the file the user wants to download. I also know of the PHP function `readfile()` but I don't see how I can implement that on the page aswell as have a HTML output shown to the user.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a META redirect, which since it points to a download will not leave the page you're on.

On your HTML page, try including something like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=/download/sitefile.zip">
```

This will browse to the file after 1 second, which should prompt the visitor to download it without leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the site http://example.com/download this can be normal html site. With redirection after few seconds (can be done in js or meta).

It should redirect to PHP site with [fpassthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) function in it. That way you can easily implement additional security in the PHP.

HINT: make sure to set proper HEADERS in the PHP file so browsers will start download the file instead of showing the content in browser screen.